# Change ListBox item visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have List box with multiple items in it like TextBlock,Image etc...

Now in the XAML file all the items visibility will be collapsed, in my .CS file based on a condition i deciding which item to display like i need to display only TextBlock or Image, but since all items visibility is collapsed by default, how to dynamically change the ListBoxItems visibility and set the data or image to the items?

Here is my XAML code:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
         SelectionChanged="TopicListboxSelectionChanged"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Name="CellBack" Margin="0,0,0,4" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Border Name="borderColor" Background="#FFF2F4F7">
                                <TextBlock Name="text"
                                       Width="456"
                                       Padding="10,20,10,20"
                                       Visibility="Collapsed"
                                       TextAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=Value}"
                                       Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                               <Image Name="Image"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Visibility="Collapsed"
                                       Width="Auto"
                                       Height="Auto"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Margin="1,1,1,1"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                     </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

**EDIT**

I am paht in my .CS file to an image source like this :

```
image = "Path to my soucre" + imagename +"phone.png";
```

Now in the the Image in XAML file how to bind this path to it ?

Usually we do it like this :

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative));
                MyImage.Source = bmp;
```

here MyImage is the name of Image in the XAML file ,but in my case i cant get the image name  which is in the list box so now how to bind the data ?

Comment: How do you decide which control to be visible, Is any `Data` with the `DataContext` of this?

Comment: I have a Object where i can check if that contains image or Text based on that i have to make either the text block or image to displayed or shown on screen, but how to do it ?

Comment: Where do your `Object` present? in the `DataContext` of `ListItem`?

Comment: What is DataContext here ? i am not aware of that, i have my object in my .CS file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a properties `TextVisiblity` and `ImageVisibility` to your view-model.  Then bind to them directly:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding TextVisibility}" ... />
        <Image Visibility="{Binding ImageVisibility}" ... />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The properties can be read-only, as in for example:

```
public Visibility TextVisibility
{
    get { return Value == null ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible; }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to modify the model class, you can use an `IValueConverter`, eg:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ModelToTextVisibility}" ... />
```

(For this you'd have to write the `ModelToTextVisibility` class, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a full example of how to do it.)

Comment: Ok, you mean to say i need add this gettersetter method in my class, and set the visibilty to that of my text ? is it in this way ? but how  can i set the visibility here? i am confused can you please elaborate

Comment: Ok let me try once i will get back to you

Comment: Ok, i have done in this way string text = myObject.Text; and in method public Visibility TextVisibility
        {
            get { return text == null ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible; }
        }
is this fine ? will it work ?

Comment: can you please check once here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905067/custom-list-box-item-style

Answer (score 1):

this is how I get a listbox item in code.

```
 ListBoxItem lbi = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(listBox.SelectedIndex) as ListBoxItem;
```

and thats how I make it invisible.

```
 lbi.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: okay that means you need to access items inside a listbox datatemplate. check this link-http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_find_a_specific_element_inside_a_control_using_Visual_tree_in_WP7... it describes the same issue.