# Custom List Box item style

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone

I have a style like below:

```
<!-- ListBox ItemTemplate style. -->
        <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseLeave">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" 
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="#d2c2f9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Margin="0,3" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="#d2c2f9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Margin="0,3" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,3"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

This is set to my list box like this :

```
    <ListBox Name="listBox" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
     </ListBox>
```

Now the  `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"` is like below;

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate">
            <Border x:Name="ListItemBorder" 
                    Margin="0,2,0,0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AnswerCellBackgroundConvertor}}">

///ITems

</Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

As you can see i have set `DataTemplate Background` as default well, so i need both the style and the converter to be present.

**Problem**

When i click on the item in the list box the style or the border is on top, like the image show below. how to set it as a background ?

Image here;

[image]

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't quit understand the full problem , but if you wan't the Content of the ListBoxItem to be exactly like the ItemTemplate replace the ContentControl with a ContentPresenter .

```
<ControlTemplate>
  <Grid>

     <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="#d2c2f9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Margin="0,3" Opacity="0"/>
     <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="#d2c2f9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Margin="0,3" Opacity="0"/>
     <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,3"/>
     <ContentPresenter   />
  </Grid>
```

```
    <Grid>                
         <Border BorderBrush="#d2c2f9" BorderThickness="1">
             <ContentPresenter   />
         </Border>

         <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,3"/>           
     </Grid>
```

edit 2 : remove the itemtemplate set the background of the listboxitem with a Setter to binding with your converter , and in your Template your Grid's Backgorund is bound to it's templated parent's background.

```
   <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">

        <!-- this -->  
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Content,Converter={StaticResource AnswerCellBackgroundConvertor}}"/>


        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                     <!-- and this Background--> 
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseLeave">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <ContnerPresenter />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="#d2c2f9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Margin="0,3" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="#d2c2f9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Margin="0,3" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,3"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but its still the same, as shown in my image

Comment: The problem : When i click on the item, the border appears on top, but it should be as a background, like in the image you can see that the text looks like its below the border color

Comment: see edit , i moved the contentpresenter up the Z-order

Comment: So the ContentPresenter  should be below the Rectangle tag ?

Comment: I did as you had suggested, but now the border color Fill="#d2c2f9" is not being applied at all, please help me

Comment: Its not that it is not applied , it's behind your contentpresenter .

just get ride of the rectangles which represent a border ,and wrap your ContentPresneter with a Border BorderBrush="#d2c2f9"  BorderThickness="1", 
or give your contentpresenter a margin of 1 - the size you want your "Border".

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say, can you please show me how? as i am new to wp8 developement

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47959/discussion-between-goofy-and-eran-otzap)